# Python XML parsing with XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I stuck with additional tag in XML. I have following XML

```
<result>
 <job>
    <tenq>15:37:53</tenq>
    <tdeq>15:37:53</tdeq>
    <tlast>15:37:53</tlast>
    <status>FIN</status>
    <id>168</id>
  </job>
  <log>
    <logs count="20" progress="100">
      <entry logid="6476178463223293277">
        <domain>1</domain>
        <receive_time>2017/10/13 15:37:50</receive_time>
        <serial>001801035328</serial>
        <seqno>6291444553</seqno>
        <----SKIP---->
        <pkts_received>0</pkts_received>
        <session_end_reason>policy-deny</session_end_reason>
        <action_source>from-policy</action_source>
      </entry>
      <----SKIP---->
    </logs>
  </log>
  <meta>
    <devices>
      <entry name="localhost.localdomain">
        <hostname>localhost.localdomain</hostname>
        <vsys>
          <entry name="vsys1">
            <display-name>vsys1</display-name>
          </entry>
        </vsys>
      </entry>
    </devices>
  </meta>
</result>
```

To get info about status I do following

```
    xml_parsed = ET.fromstring(resp.text)
    response_parsed = xml_parsed[0]
    resp_elems = response_parsed.findall('job')
```

Then I should receive number of log records and read all log entry.
To get logs I am again start with:

```
    response_parsed = xml_parsed[0]
    resp_elems = response_parsed.findall('log')
    job_status = resp_elems[0].find('entry')
```

How to get logs count ? 
Are more elegant way exists to parse info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.items()` to get the element attributes as a sequence of (name, value) pairs. Do keep in mind that the attributes are returned in an arbitrary order, so it is likely that you'd have to do some equality or membership checking to extract the info you need:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<result> ... </result>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

for x in tree.find('log'):
    print(x.items()) # [('count', '20'), ('progress', '100')]
    print(''.join(y[1] for y in x.items() if 'count' in y[0])) # 20
```